# Table values diff between installing

Tags: xml, database, oracle, synchronization

I have client and testing environments and their databases. There is simple Oracle table that contains predefined config names with their variable values.

I need to provide logging of that table, if synchronisation between client and test envs is performed through the exported dump files (exp ....dmp)?

Simply put - I have table TBL_CONFIG with values, and table TBLE_CONFIG_CHANGES that stores every update of TBL_CONFIG. But during sync data from TBL_CONFIG is being cleared and new data inserted from dump file. In this case changes are  not written into TBLE_CONFIG_CHANGES.

My first solution is before importing on test env - execute select query and write result to xml file, perform copying from client env, again execute select query of updated table to xml, and then to do diff of two xmls.

Maybe some other better solution already exists for such case?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to handle this which you mentioned. Apart from this, you can check below ways: 
 
1. If you keep imp log open/configured, it gives you number of rows inserted. 
2. If you have any timestamp/date field in the table, then you can query using that. 
3. You can use ora_rowscn values to compare for the changed data. Example of ora_rowscn 
SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ora_rowscn)) from myTable; 
4. OR, Enable auditing

> AUDIT INSERT ON user.table
>   
>   Then query USER_AUDIT_OBJECT. 
>   Hope it helps. I am ready for details too. Ask me if any confusion.

Comment: Thanx for you response, but it's not applicable for my case. I need to track only changes in variable columns of predefined rows ( configuration names are not changed, only their values). Table of test environment is being cleared before inserting new data from client environment.

Comment: Then, keeping old table and using one sql or pl/sql script will be helpful I think. Also, if there is a chance to use dblink, then direct comparison is possible rather keeping old table.